# PHP variable mutation. Array passed to function becomes a 1

Tags: php

Function call:

```
 $trdata .= $this->table_td($tddata, 1, $td);
```

Function:

```
public function table_td($data = '', $parameters = array()){
    return($this->table_thtd($data, 0, $parameters));
}
```

A print_r before the return shows a 1, instead of the data array I'm passing. Any thoughts on what's going on?

Comment: Just to rub it in: in python, `def table_td(data = '', *parameters):` will do exactly what you think PHP should be doing.

Comment: That doesn't Python cool. It just makes Python different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing a `1` as the second argument to the function call, and your `$parameters` argument is the second argument in the function definition... what do you expect?

Comment: Apparently I should have gone to bed a little earlier than I did.

Answer (score 1):

Two-argument function:

```
public function table_td(
    $data = '',            # one
    $parameters = array()  # two
) { ... }
```

Three-argument function call:

```
$trdata .= $this->table_td(
    $tddata,              # one
    1,                    # two
    $td                   # three
);
```

Hmmm. And you wonder why the second parameter (`$parameters`) gets set to the second argument (`1`)?